# Sublime Text Markmon package, render with github markdown style?

Tags: css, sublimetext3, markdown, pandoc

I am trying to get the markmon package for sublime text to render my markdown with the GitHub styles, but I've had no luck.

I've tried various things to convince the preferences to invoke a different style sheet, to no avail.

Here are my preferences:

`{
    "executable": "markmon",
    "port": 3002,
    "pandoc_path": "/usr/bin/pandoc",
    "command": "pandoc -t HTML5",
    "stylesheet": null,
    "projectdir": null
}`

I'm on Linux, and I have a local copy of the style-sheet I can employ, but so far all attempts to supply it have caused strange behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more hacking about I found that an explicit call to the style document can be made as such:

`{
    "executable": "markmon",
    "port": 3002,
    "pandoc_path": "/usr/bin/pandoc",
    "command": "pandoc -t HTML5",
    "stylesheet": "/home/jeremy/.pandoc/style.css",
    "projectdir": null
}`

You can then confirm this by running markmon and looking at the stylesheet from the page source.

A big comment at the start of the stylesheet document is handy for confirmation.

Note: the markmon plugin does not live reload this stylesheet, you have to tell sublime text to stop markmon and restart markmon to have it reload the stylesheet. I'd be curious on how to change that behavior to a live reload.

The markmon plugin itself however will not added the proper classes to elements that use GitHub's extended markdown, so things like checklist list items will not work without hacking in a way for the initial document processing to add the right tags.

I'm not sure where that processing takes place or how to go about finding out.